# Can you "do a goal" or do you have to "meet a goal?"

Tags: verb-agreement, phrasing

If I am asking a client what they will be doing to meet a fitness goal, i.e. riding a bike to be more active (the goal is to be more active). Can I say, "how will you do your goal?" in a goal setting worksheet?

Answer (score 3):

A *goal* is a place (albeit sometimes a metaphoric one), not a thing or an action. Thus, you can *reach* a goal, *work towards* a goal, *work on* a goal, *meet* a goal, or any number of other verbs; and you can do *my homework*, do *your hair*, do *a job*, or any number of other "things you do"; but you cannot *do* a *goal*.

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

*How will you meet your goal?*

less common:

*How will you complete your goal?*

Comment: Note that “accomplishing a goal” is fairly common and accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can *fulfill, achieve or accomplish* your goals also.

As for [fitness goals](http://www.aworkoutroutine.com/what-is-your-fitness-goal/) ... *How are you going to reach your goal* may be a useful expression.

Comment: You can also *score* a goal!

Comment: Is it incorrect though to say "do" a goal?

Comment: It is unusual to me, I'd not suggest to use it. Did you read or hear 'do a goal' somewhere?

Comment: Thanks @Josh61 ... I think I'll change it to "how will you work on your goal?"

Comment: In the link you'll find a few ideas on how to use 'goals' talking  about fitness.

Comment: We do not say do a goal because a goal is not something that is done. It is the outcome of doing something. So, if my goal is to ride my bike 10 miles a day, what I do is to ride the bike. When I have done so I have accomplished, met, fulfilled, achieved, or reached my goal. The doing, however, was about riding, and not about the goal.